# Socket.io in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, sockets, http, express, socket.io

I am using `socket.io` in a NodeJS app. The `socket.io` page is in  `localhost:8081/socket.io/`. However, I would like to have it in `localhost:8081/hola/socket.io/`. Is that possible?

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var server = require("http").Server(app);
var io = require("socket.io")(server);
//some code here...
server.listen(8081, function() {
    console.log("Server running at http://localhost:8081/");
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pass in `path` in the options array which is the second option to `socket.io`:

```
var io = require("socket.io")(server, { path: '/hola/socket.io'});
```